# How do I remove vertex from vertex groups to edit hair particle system?

Tags: particles, vertex-groups, hair

As you can see my characters beard is spreading over his neck a bit too much. I cannot find a way to remove the neck verticies from the beard vertex group sucessfully and have it re edit the hair.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing vertices is fairly straightforward; select the verts and click the "Remove" button right next to "Assign" while your group is highlighted.

[image: Remove button]

If the problem is that the changes aren't showing up then you can usually rectify this by changing the "Seed" input (seen below) to force an update.

[image: The seed input]

Aside from that, make sure you aren't applying any Particlesystem modifiers as that will finalise any changes you make. If none of these solve your problem then I don't think I fully understand what the problem is, perhaps you could be more specific

[EDIT] Blender doesn't allow retroactive edits to particle systems that have been edited in "Particle Edit". However there are tricks to overcome this issue:

- You can control many aspects of the hair including length and density using weight painting as seen in the "Vertex Groups" section (Verts in a groups are assigned a uniform weight of 100% by default which can give unrealistic results)
- Your image has strand of hair grouped into superstrands which each end in a point, all of these things can be achieved with the "Children" panel which appears when you tick "Advanced".
- If you wish to point all the strands downwards you can give them an initial velocity or just give them physics and let a simulation handle it (I personally think this is more effort than it's worth)

Always make sure you've finalised your particle settings before you go into Particle Edit

Comment: the seed input is uneditable, it says "free edit" do I need to adjust this?

Comment: it says I will lose the edits done in particle mode

Comment: I've checked the documentation and I'm afraid that can't be helped, I've edited the answer to address this problem